# Newbe problems and first steps

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongodb-.net-driver

I just start with MongoDB.
I have installed it on Win Server 2008 R2 and hosted it in a win Service, worked.
I tried to connect from a Client using an app, but can't connect.
I checked the Connection string twice, correct (isn't that hard) and I stopped the Firewalls on both machines, nothing helped. The machines were part of a private Network, no Routers in between.
I also used mongo Shell (mongo.exe) on the Server, and I was able to connect.
So, it must be some issue with the Client machine or the Network.

Comment: What does stand for "can't connect"? Please add error/code with question.

Comment: Hi,I just get a timeout, nothing more to see ... Have a Screen shot, but no idea how to attach here. With best rehards Gerhard  PS: Even don't know how to add a new line ... iggrrr